# copy from text file into DataTable needs to be split

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("test");
            col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);

            string[] aa = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\aaaaa\\Desktop\\aaaaa.txt");
            foreach (var item in aa)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = item.ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

My text file contains

```
hi;my;name;is;xyz
```

separator is ";"

but I want to write my data to data Table  like that

```
hi
my
name
is
xyz
```

How can I change my code to work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split each line by `;`, then add a record for each of the outputted segments.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn col = new DataColumn("test");
col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dt.Columns.Add(col);

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\aaaaa\\Desktop\\aaaaa.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var segments = line.Split(';');
    foreach (var seg in segments)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = seg;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: @jidravafyo you mean your dataGrid ?.. make sure you have this line `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`, I didn't include it in my answer.